# box2d for flash how to compile its examples?

Tags: actionscript-3

http://box2dflash.sourceforge.net/

i downloaded the code and in its folder there is a examples folder. How can i compile them ? what are the other software i need and how can i do it? Please help me because iam completely new to the actionscript programming side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is explained in the Examples/Readme.txt

As quoted from the Readme

> //
>   To compile the demo:
>   //
>
> Flash:  extract Box2DFlashAS3 and open
>   PhysTest.fla in Flash CS3 (9) and hit
>   Ctrl+Enter.
>
> Flex: Create a new
>   ActionScript project and add all the files from the archive to the project.
>   Set Main.as to the default application and hit Ctrl+F11.
>
> MXMLC: From the
>   "Examples" directory, run: mxmlc
>   -source-path=../Source/ Main.as;

Thus you have three different ways to compile.

1. Use Flash CS3 (or [higher](https://www.adobe.com/cfusion/tdrc/index.cfm?product=flash))
2. Use Flex Builder (or [higher](https://www.adobe.com/cfusion/tdrc/index.cfm?product=flash_builder) )
3. Use the [Flex SDK](http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/entitlement/index.cfm?e=flex4sdk) that contains mxmlc

Comment: @user581544 Yes, I believe so. There should be the option to add it via the preferences pane. Preferences -> Flex SDK -> Installed SDK (At least this is what I have for Eclipse 3.4)

Comment: @user581544 yes under their [terms](http://www.adobe.com/products/eulas/pdfs/adobe_flex_software_development_kit_combined_20100101_1530.pdf) that you do not modify the SDK and some other things. But yes it is free to use to develop applications.

Answer (score 2):

Only posting this as an answer because I can't post a comment... this is an alternative box2D implementation that uses alchemy (so much faster) but the real up-side to it is that it has plugins for the flash UI to visually design/create physical objects, including building worlds etc. Video tutorial explains where to download:

http://gotoandlearn.com/play.php?id=135